# How to connect to GKE Private cluster from an instance present in another VPC?

Tags: networking, google-kubernetes-engine, vpc

I have the following resources in GCP platform

1. GKE Private Cluster with Private Endpoint in xyz VPC
2. A Private instance in the same VPC as the cluster (xyz VPC), say ubuntu-vm-xyz
3. A Private instance in another VPC (lmn VPC), say ubuntu-vm-lmn

I was able to connect to Cluster from ubuntu-vm-xyz as the VPC peering between Google and xyz VPC gets automatically created.

And I was not able to connect to Cluster from ubuntu-vm-lmn as the VPC peering between Google and lmn VPC has to be manually created. I can created Peering setup from my side to Google's network.

How can we do the peering from the Google end for lmn VPC?

Answer (score 9):

[The document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept#the_master_in_private_clusters) mentioned “Every GKE cluster has a Kubernetes API server called the [master](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#master). The master is in a Google-owned project that is separate from your project. It runs on a VM that is in a VPC network in the Google-owned project.”  and “In private clusters, the master's VPC network is connected to your cluster's VPC network with [VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering). Your VPC network contains the cluster nodes, and a separate Google Cloud VPC network contains your cluster's master. ” this you are able to reach the private endpoint from ubuntu-vm-xyz as it is in same vpc network.

Now it also explained why ubuntu-vm-lmn is not being able to reach Endpoints in private clusters. As it already mentioned your master node is in google managed project so you do not have access to that vpc. And as per [the document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering#example_vpc_network_peering_setup) the vpc peering required below three steps:

- Step 1: Peer network-a with network-b
- Step 2: Peer network-b with network-a
- Step 3: VPC Network Peering becomes ACTIVE

So you can not complete the vpc peering with google owned project. Also the VPC does not supports “[Transitive peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#restrictions)”. Therefore, creating vpc peering between xyz and lmn will not work.

Now, the simpler solution is enable  [master authorized networks](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept#overview) and add your network in [aster-authorized-networks](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/authorized-networks#add) with the help of the document.

Alternatively you can try to create a [VM as NAT gateway](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#natgateway) between the two vpc. But, honestly I did not test that one personally.

Note: I would like to post this as comment but due to limitation of the character limit post as answer. please feel free to add question or comments on this, I will modify this post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly a duplicate, but the essence is the same as [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56877125/9231144)

Another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58818376/how-to-make-gke-clusters-communicate-using-private-ips-or-networks/58829068#58829068) touches on this as well.

Notice that [Global access](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#global_access_beta) should also address this issue though it is not clear if Google will enable this feature on the Master private endpoint